# Kubernetes DNS not resolving

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I try to spin up a small kubernetes cluster consisting of just a frontend and a backend, but I can't get it to work. My main problem is that my frontend cannot find my backend through the defined service. What am I missing here? Maybe it's worth to mention that I work with minikube.

frontend

```
useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get("http://simplebackend-service:8080/");
    setData(result.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

fetchData();
  }, []);
```

backend

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
var cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    hey: "hello my friend",
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

simple-frontend.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simplefrontend-deployment
  labels:
    app: simplefrontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: simplefrontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: simplefrontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: simplefrontend
          image: image
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: simplefrontend-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: simplefrontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      nodePort: 30100
```

simple-backend.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: simplebackend-deployment
  labels:
    app: simplebackend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: simplebackend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: simplebackend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: simplebackend
          image: image
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: simplebackend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: simplebackend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

after I have applied the deployments and services with the command `kubectl apply -f ...` to the cluster, I create a tunnel to the frontend using the `minikube service simplefrontend-service` command. There I get the error net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED displayed. Why is that not working, What am I missing here?

Comment: can you port forward your front end service without any issues ?

Comment: The `axios.get()` call is running in the end user's browser.  That's not inside the Kubernetes cluster, and it can't use Kubernetes Service names as host names.  You need to set up an Ingress object to reach your backend (or something else equivalent) and point your front-end application at that endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the manifest and the application config.

```
await axios.get("http://simplebackend-service/");
```

it should specify backend port and namespace (if running in a different namespace) i.e `SERVICENAME.NAMESPACE:SERVICE_PORT`

```
await axios.get("http://simplebackend-service:SERVICE_PORT/");
```

Backend service should be pointing to right port

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: simplebackend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: simplebackend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 8080
```

`targetport` should be `8080` as the backend listening on port `8080`

Comment: I updatet the ports (and the values in my question). If I now curl into http://simplebackend-service:8080/ I get the expected response back. But my frontend still can't access it. Any ideas?

Comment: the frontend should be using `simplebackend-service:27017`